# Using an older deployment after update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm trying to make a wedding website using this person's blog/github: https://blog.rampatra.com/wedding-website. I had this to where when someone filled out the form on my website, I received an email and my google spreadsheet updated. Then we needed a shorter invite code, so I changed the logic. Now, when I enter the new code, I get an error message saying the new code is invalid and the old code still works even though anything other than the new code should be throwing an error.

I have an HTML form on my index.html exactly like the original.

I also have a section in my scripts.js that was identical to the example:

```
/********************** RSVP **********************/
$('#rsvp-form').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var data = $(this).serialize();

$('#alert-wrapper').html(alert_markup('info', '<strong>Just a sec!</strong> We are 
saving your details.'));

if (MD5($('#invite_code').val()) !== 'b0e53b10c1f55ede516b240036b88f40'
    && MD5($('#invite_code').val()) !== '2ac7f43695eb0479d5846bb38eec59cc') {
    $('#alert-wrapper').html(alert_markup('danger', '<strong>Sorry!</strong> Your 
invite code is incorrect.'));
} else {

$.post
('https://script.google.com/macros/s/<my deployment id>-/exec', data)
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.result === "error") {
                $('#alert-wrapper').html(alert_markup('danger', data.message));
            } else {
                $('#alert-wrapper').html('');
                $('#rsvp-modal').modal('show');
            }
        })
        .fail(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#alert-wrapper').html(alert_markup('danger', '<strong>Sorry!</strong> 
There is some issue with the server. '));
        });
}
});
```

For my google sheet, I used the example script and initially only changed the email address

```
var TO_ADDRESS = "youremailaddress@gmail.com"; // email to send the form data to

/**
* This method is the entry point.
*/
function doPost(e) {

try {
Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger

var mailData = e.parameters; // just create a slightly nicer variable name for the 
data

if (mailData.invite_code != "271117") { // validate invite code before saving data
  Logger.log("Incorrect Invite Code");
  return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "message": "Sorry, your 
invite code (" + mailData.invite_code + ") is incorrect."}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

record_data(e);

MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: TO_ADDRESS,
  subject: "A new guest RSVP'd for your wedding",
  replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form 
 actually collecting a field named `email`
  htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData)
});

return ContentService    // return json success results
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success","data": 
JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
} catch(error) { // if error return this
Logger.log(error);
return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "message": "Sorry, there is 
an issue with the server."}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
}


/**
* This method inserts the data received from the html form submission
* into the sheet. e is the data received from the POST
*/
function record_data(e) {
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // log the POST data in case we need to debug it
try {
var doc     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet   = doc.getSheetByName('responses'); // select the responses sheet
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
var row     = [ new Date().toUTCString() ]; // first element in the row should always 
be a timestamp
// loop through the header columns
for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column
  if(headers[i].length > 0) {
    row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]); // add data to row
  }
}
// more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
}
catch(error) {
Logger.log(error);
Logger.log(e);
throw error;
}
finally {
return;
}
}
```

After I got the example working, I changed my Google AppScript to `if(mailData.invite_code !="271117")` to a new code and then hit deploy -> new deployment. I copied the new deployment ID and hit deploy. The new version seemed to deploy.

In scripts.js I changed:

```
  (MD5($('#invite_code').val()) !== 'b0e53b10c1f55ede516b240036b88f40'
```

to the hash of the new code and

```
  $.post
  ('https://script.google.com/macros/s/<my deployment id>-/exec', data)
```

to the new deployment id

I saved my code with the new deployment id, committed, and ran terraform apply and updated the S3 bucket. I went back to my website and completed the RSVP form again.

The website changes URL to one that has the json response and says "Sorry, your invite code (mycode) is incorrect". That code matches the code in my script exactly. If I fill out a new RSVP with the code from the example, it works as if I didn't change anything. When I check the 'executions' table in Apps Scripts, the deployment version kicked off is the older one.

Do I need to archive the old deployment? Is there a delay, and if there is a delay why isn't my scripts.js failing?

Comment: When the Web Apps is deployed as a new version, `<my deployment id>-` of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/<my deployment id>-/exec` is changed. In this case, the old URL has the old script before you modified it. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. When you want to redeploy your Web Apps without changing the deployment ID, you can achieve this by [this flow](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43). If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Do you not surely need to check the value of `e.postData` rather than `e.parameters`? The latter are url parameters which would be of the form `/exec?invite_code=271117` at the end of the url. Have you tried logging the values of `e.postData` and `e.parameters?